# Duplicated BigQuery rows from Cloud Logging sink

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-logging

I've set sink to transfer logs from Google Cloud Logging to BigQuery. Everything works fine, but **sometimes** there will be duplicated rows from the same log in Cloud Logging

Here is an example for cloud Logging. There's only one log here.
[image]

And here's what I get when I query this record from BigQuery with insertId: 1fw0b92g26o229x
[image]

Anybody has the same issue? and can I prevent this duplication.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duplicates can occur when there are failures in streaming logs to BQ, or it could also happen anywhere during upstream including the client side. BQ currently does not de-duplicate the data. If the **receiveTimestamp** are all the same, the duplicates would have occurred somewhere in the logging pipeline or inside the BigQuery streaming ingestion. There is currently no way to have a perfect de-duplication at ingest time. The duplicates will need to be removed at query time.

You don't see the duplicates in the Logs Viewer because it de-duplicates the logs with the same timestamp and insertId at query time. It might  be possible to do the same in BQ by querying it with GROUP BY as in the below example query.

```
SELECT timestamp,severity,insertId
FROM project-id.my_dataset.my_table 
GROUP BY timestamp,severity,insertId
```

Comment: Do you mean that it's possible that 1 row of log in cloud logging can be exported and duplicated by GCP sink to BigQuery?

Comment: @Lazywii I have edited my answer as per your query.

Answer (score 2):

Cloud Logging considers the log entries in the same project, with the same timestamp, and with the same insertId to be **duplicates** which are removed in a single query result.

However, there are no guarantees of de-duplication in the export of logs.

Refer [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry#:%7E:text=no%20guarantees%20of-,de-duplication,-in%20the%20export) for more details.

Comment: From my service, I submit the log to Cloud Logging only once without specifying insertId. Does it mean that Cloud Logging also duplicates my log?

Comment: Can you provide an export of BigQuery logs.

Comment: Sorry I didn't catch your point. Do you mean the log in cloud logging? My problem is that in Cloud Logging, there's only 1 row, but it appears in BigQuery 4 duplicated rows